# Show that a $y \in R$ exists,so that $|g(y)|\leq|g(x)|$

Tags: analysis

It is given that $g$ is a polynomial function.Show that a $y \in R$ exists,so that $|g(y)|\leq|g(x)| , \forall x \in R$. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use these three facts:

1. $|g(x)|$ is bounded below
2. $|g(x)|$ is continuous
3. $\lim_{x\to\infty}|g(x)|=\infty$ (if the degree of $g$ is $\ge1$.)

Comment: How can I use these facts to show that there is such a $y$ ?